# SQL multi-part identifier error on Update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Could anyone point me out the issue in below update query?

[image]

Comment: I referred some of the previous question asked on the same issue but could not figure out the issue in here.

Answer (score 1):

The other column is in another table. You must join your table like this (is an example between two table, I can't give you the exact query since I don't know how is your schema):

```
UPDATE A SET
  A.COLUMN1 = 1
FROM TABLE1 AS A
JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to refer to a table you have to use use it in `FROM` or `JOIN` clause:

```
UPDATE dbo.SALES_ORD_HDR
SET X_PickingSlip_Printed = 1
WHERE SEQNO IN (SELECT HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ FROM dbo.SALESORDHIST);
                                         -- here you are refering table
```

alternatively using correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE dbo.SALES_ORD_HDR
SET X_PickingSlip_Printed = 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.SALESORDHIST
              WHERE dbo.SALES_ORD_HDR.SEQNO = dbo.SALESORDHIST.HEADER_SOURCE_SEQ);
```